# Remove leading and trailing characters except between the digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is an example of input value:

```
00080a7a00
```

and the expected output of this input:

```
80a7
```

To get the expected output i tried the following query:

```
set @ttt='00080a7a00'
select SUBSTRING(@ttt,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',@ttt),LEN(@ttt))
```

And i am getting this output:

```
80a7a00
```

So i am looking for the correct query to have the expected output.

Comment: Are the leading and trailing characters always 0s?

Comment: Any characters other than 1-9

Comment: You could use a tally table to split the characters of the string into rows.

Comment: Is the string a fixed length?

Comment: @SteveC Variable length

Comment: Is there a maximum length?

Comment: Consider 20 if it is important

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *... remove leading and trailing characters except between the digits ...*, starting from SQL Server 2017, you may use `TRIM()` to remove the specified characters from the start and the end of a string (`TRIM()` function accepts literal or variable containing characters that should be removed as first parameter):

```
DECLARE @text varchar(100)
DECLARE @chars varchar(100)

SELECT @text = '00080a7a00'
SELECT @chars = CONCAT(
   LEFT(@text, PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', @text) - 1),
   LEFT(REVERSE(@text), PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', REVERSE(@text)) - 1)
)   
SELECT TRIM(@chars FROM @text)
```

Result:

```
80a7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REVERSE` to find the trailing characters:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@ttt,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',@ttt),2+LEN(@ttt) -PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',@ttt) - PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',REVERSE(@ttt)))
```